# Monitoring GitLab with an external Prometheus

Tags: gitlab, prometheus

I am trying to configure gitlab to be monitored from a external prometheus that I have deployed in kubernetes.
I am following the instructions in the documentation.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/#using-an-external-prometheus-server

```
gitlab_workhorse['prometheus_listen_addr'] = "0.0.0.0:9229"

# Rails nodes
gitlab_exporter['listen_address'] = '0.0.0.0'
gitlab_exporter['listen_port'] = '9168'

# Sidekiq nodes
sidekiq['listen_address'] = '0.0.0.0'

# Redis nodes
redis_exporter['listen_address'] = '0.0.0.0:9121'

# PostgreSQL nodes
postgres_exporter['listen_address'] = '0.0.0.0:9187'

# Gitaly nodes
gitaly['prometheus_listen_addr'] = "0.0.0.0:9236"
```

These services I can see from prometheus.
Where I have problems is in steps 5 and 6 to configure the gitlab_rails

```
5. Add the Prometheus server IP address to the monitoring IP whitelist. For example:

gitlab_rails['monitoring_whitelist'] = ['127.0.0.0/8', '192.168.0.1']

6. On all GitLab Rails(Puma/Unicorn, Sidekiq) servers, set the Prometheus server IP address and listen port. For example:

gitlab_rails['prometheus_address'] = '192.168.0.1:9090'
```

If my prometheus is deployed in kubernetes which IP should I put ?

Answer (score 0):

Check again [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/#using-an-external-prometheus-server), of which the steps have changed (including step 5)

See [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#bring-your-own-prometheus-for-the-best-gitlab-kubernetes-integrated-experience) (April 2021)

> ### Bring your own Prometheus for the best GitLab - Kubernetes integrated experience
>
> By integrating your cluster services with GitLab you can benefit from various GitLab features, like [Environment boards](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_boards.html), [Prometheus metrics](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/metrics/), and [application logs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/kubernetes_pod_logs.html).
>
> Previously, these features required you to use GitLab Managed Apps which did not suit the workflow and requirements of many of our users.
>
> With this release, you can integrate with Prometheus and Kubernetes through GitLab services and keep their maintenance on your end, following your own company processes and policies.
>
> We provide extensive documentation and a recommended workflow on how to install these applications if you are just getting started. You can still hold the deep metrics integrations available in GitLab as you had with GitLab Managed Prometheus.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/integrations.html#prometheus-cluster-integration) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/292460).